# etiquetas <script> llamando funciones de firebase no funcionan

Tags: javascript, firebase, script, meta-tags

Tengo el siguiente HTML con la estructura basica de Firebase llamando el modulo de autenticacion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"></meta>    
        <title>ADMON 2 - DULCESITA</title>    
        <!--jQuery-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/clases/autenticacion.js"></script>
        <!--fireBase-->        
        <script type="module">
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
            import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, getDocs, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-firestore.js";
            import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-auth.js";          

            const firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyDfAa64FCuk0iS5B-smO2_PTFG2wFeVWPk",
                authDomain: "dulcesita---admon.firebaseapp.com",
                projectId: "dulcesita---admon",
                storageBucket: "dulcesita---admon.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "744343616348",
                appId: "1:744343616348:web:6a9fe8937821ca55849f99",
                measurementId: "G-2PXV2G74KB"
            };

            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 

          
              //Si traigo aca la clase Autenticacion, todo funciona bien


            $("#btnInicioEmail").click(() => {                
                const email = $('#emailSesion').val();
                const password = $('#passwordSesion').val();
                const ObjIniciarSesion = new Autenticacion;
                ObjIniciarSesion.iniciarSesionCorreoPassword(email,password);                        
            });            

        </script>

              
        <!--Bootstrap con material desing-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/mdb.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css"></link>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"></link>    
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"></link>
       
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="headerppal">
            <figure class="header-logotipo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Blog Logotipo">
            </figure>
            <h2 class="titulo">Clase Firebase</h2>                                            
                <input id="emailSesion" type="email" required/>
                <input id="passwordSesion" type="password" required />
                <a id="btnInicioEmail">Iniciar Sesión</a>
                
        </header>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Tengo la clase Autenticacion en el archivo autenticacion.js

```
class Autenticacion {
    iniciarSesionCorreoPassword(email, password){
        const auth = getAuth();                                  
        
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) =>{
            // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            //console.log(user);
            console.log("inicio sesion exitoso")
            // ...
        }).catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    }
}
```

Si coloco el codigo donde dije arriba en el HTML despues de inicializar firebase, todo funciona bien, pero al ponerlo en el arhcivo autenticacion.js y llamarlo con

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clases/autenticacion.js"></script>
```

no funciona, ya me aseguré de que este bien la ruta pues borro la clase y pongo un alert ahi en autenticacion.js y efectivamente lo hace al cargar la pagina

el error que me arroja es
Uncaught ReferenceError: getAuth is not defined

Gracias!